# What does the $d^*$ and $P^*$ mean in the Slater's condition?why when they are equal means the strong duality holds?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Here is question and solution,but i didn't understand the solution,can anyone help me to understand it?

min $-3x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_3^2$

$s.t. x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$

Does the strong duality hold?

Solution:

Let 
A=\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}and $X=[x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$,so now rewrite as

min $X^TAX$,so its lagragian function is $X^TAX+\mu(X^TX-1)$,so

dual problem is

max $-\mu$

$s.t. A+\mu I \ge 0$

$ A+\mu I \ge 0$,so $\mu \ge -\lambda\ min(A)=3$,that is $d^*=-\mu=-3$

$P^*=\lambda\ min(A)=-3$,so $d^*=P^*$,it means strong duality holds

My question is

$1.$ Where is the $d^*$ and $P^*$,because i don't see them in the solution formula and question,i know they are about the Slater's condition,but i don't know what is their meaning in this solution,why when $d^*=P^*$ means strong duality holds?

$2.$ About this formula,$ A+\mu I \ge 0$,so $\mu \ge -\lambda\ min(A)=3$,where is $\lambda\ min(A)$ from? it just appeared suddenly

Comment: $d^*$ is the dual objective value, $P^*$ is the primal objective value and $\lambda_{min}(A)$ is the minimal eigenvalue (here: entry on diagonal) in $A$.

Comment: so $\lambda \ min (A) =P^* $  is the definition of $P^*$?if not,how to know the $P^*$ is  equal to $\lambda \ min (A)  $ ?

Comment: You can solve the original optimization problem by hand and then you get $P^*$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek so what is  $P^*$ ? $x?$ or $A$? I know $d^*$ is optimal dual problem ,that is , $-\mu$